# Struggling with classList.add and getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to add a extra class to some elements with a specific class(input-fieldset).

```
<fieldset id="pay" class="input-fieldset"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="address" class="input-fieldset"></fieldset>
```

So I did some searches and found this:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('input-fieldset');
element.classList.add(' input-fieldset-awesome');
```

I'm trying to add the class input-fieldset-awesome.

But it doesn't work, I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined(anonymous function)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are getting an array of elements from `getElementsByClassName`, try targeting only a particular element

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (array of objects) that must be iterated.

The code below will accomplish what you're after.

```
// Get desired elements
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('input-fieldset');

// Iterate through the retrieved elements and add the necessary class names.
for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++)
{
    element[i].classList.add('input-fieldset-awesome');
    console.log(element[i].className);
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/6LasT/1/).

Comment: [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList), ([compatibility](http://caniuse.com/classlist)).

Comment: Classlist is a cleaner. better and relatively new way to add classes to elements. It doesn't involve manipulating the `className` string

Comment: Thanks for the heads up guys. I modified my code to reflect your comments.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'v been looking for it all day, finally you gave me the working code

Comment: Is it the same code to remove class?

Comment: @Khalil, yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

In your case you should modify your code like this.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('input-fieldset')[0];
element.classList.add(' input-fieldset-awesome');
```

or

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('input-fieldset');
for (var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].classList.add('input-fieldset-awesome');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` which doesn't have `classList` property, you should iterate through the collection.

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('input-fieldset'))
  .forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.classList.add('cls');
  });
```