# How to reference/modify elements in a class list found by using a jQuery class selector

Tags: jquery

Before I get to my question, consider the following code, which seems to work with jQuery:

```js
var $element = $('.input-fieldset');

$element.each(function(){
  $(this)[0].classList.add("input-fieldset-awesome");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="pay" class="input-fieldset"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="address" class="input-fieldset"></fieldset>
```

I discovered that the above seemed to work after first running into problems with this:

```js
var $element = $('.input-fieldset');
$element.classList.add("input-fieldset-awesome");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="pay" class="input-fieldset"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="address" class="input-fieldset"></fieldset>
```

Which throws an error:

> Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

In my struggle to find a solution, I found that someone else had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219702/struggling-with-classlist-add-and-getelementsbyclassname), but in that example, they weren't using jQuery. Also, it was found to be a duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method), which the top answer suggested that `$('.myElement').css('size', '100px');` was possible. But if that should work, then why doesn't this:

```
$('.input-fieldset').classList.add("input-fieldset-awesome");
```

That was the first question; my other question is this: in my working solution above, I used "[0]" to de-reference the first element in the $(this) object which I know should have only one element in it, but is that really the best solution?  (It seems strange to me that I should need the "[0]" at all...)

Answer (score 1):

`.classList` is a property on *native* `HTMLElement`s. `$('<selector>')` returns a jQuery collection, which is quite different. jQuery collection methods do not have the same names as element methods.

jQuery does have a function that lets you add classes, though, via `addClass`, which will add the selected class to every element in the collection:

```js
var $elements = $('.input-fieldset');
$elements.addClass("input-fieldset-awesome");
```

```css
.input-fieldset-awesome {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="pay" class="input-fieldset"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="address" class="input-fieldset"></fieldset>
```

Note that since jQuery collections are *collections* and not single elements (generally), it would be good to name the variables appropriately - that is, for example, `var $elements` rather than `var $element`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has it's own class changing methods like [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/), [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Mixing native dom methods and jQuery ones  can make your code base hard to read through and confusing.

For example it makes no sense to do `$(this)[0]` which just returns `this`

Use one or the other and stick to the same approach throughout.